# unable to set number of digits after decimal using paste function (R)

Tags: r, decimal, paste

I'm trying to set the number of digits after decimal to 1.
I have done this computation:

```
options(digits = 3)
DT<-data.table(x=c("a","b","c",NA,"b","e"),v=rnorm(6))
ans<-DT[,lapply(.SD,function(x) length(which(is.na(x)))/length(x)*100)]
```

Now, ans gives me the percentage of NAs in a column:

```
  x v
  16.7 0
```

But when I try to add the percent symbol "%" with:

```
ans[,lapply(.SD, function(x) paste(x,"%",sep = ''))]
```

The decimal digits are back there:

```
                    x   v
1: 16.6666666666667% 0%
```

What am I doing wrong? how can I get this output?:

```
 x v
 16.7% 0%
```

Thank you.

Comment: Also `round`, like `ans<-DT[,lapply(.SD,function(x) round(length(which(is.na(x)))/length(x)*100, 1))]` then your final step. Note that `options(digits = 3)` controls the number of digits that are printed, not the number of digits that R is storing for each number.

Comment: Useful explanation, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can just use `sprintf` by converting it to two decimal places and concatenate with `%`

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sprintf("%0.1f%%", 100*sum(is.na(x))/.N))]
```

---

Or we can just use `format`

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) paste0(format(100*sum(is.na(x))/.N, digits = 3), "%"))]
#      x  v
#1: 16.7% 0%
```

Answer (score 6):

you can just use `round` and do :

```
paste0(round(ans,1),"%")
```

which gives

```
[1] "16.7%" "0%"
```

or changing OP's code to:

```
ans[,lapply(.SD, function(x) paste(round(x,1),"%",sep = ''))]
```